# Compute New Data Frame from Multiple Rows

Tags: r

This is a super newbie question, but I'm getting totally lost reading the documentation. I have a csv that specifies user_id and scoretype (a data value that can be one of "tp", "fp", or "fn" for true positive, false positive, false negative respectively).

So my data looks like this:

```
user_id, type, value
1         tp     342
1         fp     22
1         fn     25
2         tp     232
2         fp     342
2         fn     3
```

etc

I want to compute an F1 score from this data. I've written a function that takes the tp, fp, and fn as arguments, but first I need to rearrange this table so that the score type becomes a column:

```
user_id, tp, fp, fn
1        342  22  25
etc
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(dat,user_id ~ type,fun.aggregate = sum,value.var = 'value')
  user_id fn  fp  tp
1       1 25  22 342
2       2  3 342 232
```

I should point out, I suppose, that this assumes that there will only be a single value for each variable for each user (otherwise `sum` isn't going to be the right choice).

Comment: That works! Thank you so much. I'll have a ways to go before I understand what is meant by much of the lexicon in the documentation.  Molten data is a new one for me.

Comment: Yes, there is a single value for each user in this case. :)